# How to get past firmware lock in iMac?

Tags: imac, firmware

My 27inch imac has locked firmware, after working ok the day before
will not go into recovery mode can i bypass this, as apple say because i
bought it second hand and not from apple they cant help?

Comment: Do you have a proof of purchase?

Comment: Yes i do i took a copy from paypal ebay.

Comment: You might want to try whether Apple accepts this. Or reach out to the seller.

Comment: Has the seller removed the iMac from their registered devices?